# Getting Java heap space error when using ehcache with Terracotta

Tags: java, exception, ehcache, heap-memory, terracotta

I am trying to use Terracotta with ehcache. My project has two instances of Tomcat where my application integrated with ehcache is deployed. I need synchronization between these two instances, which is why I am using Terracotta. However I am facing error:

> net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Uncaught exception in get() - Java heap space

when I have integrated ehcache with Terracotta. My ehcache.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ehcache name="terracotta" maxBytesLocalHeap="30%" >
  <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

 <terracottaConfig url="localhost:9510"/>
 <cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
 class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"/>

<cache name="LocalCache"
        timeToLiveSeconds="10"
    maxElementsOnDisk="0"
        eternal="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" >
      <terracotta />           
</cache>


<cache name="cache1"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10"
    maxElementsOnDisk="0"
        eternal="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" >
      <terracotta />          
</cache>

<cache name="cache2"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10"
    maxElementsOnDisk="0"
        eternal="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" >
      <terracotta /> 
      </cache>

<cache name="cache3"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10"
    maxElementsOnDisk="0"
        eternal="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" >
            <terracotta />
</cache>

      <cache name="cache4"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10"
    maxElementsOnDisk="0"
        eternal="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" >
     <terracotta /> 
</cache>

 <cache name="cache5"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10"
    maxElementsOnDisk="0"
        eternal="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" >
      <terracotta />    
     </cache>

<cache name="cache6"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10"
    maxElementsOnDisk="0"
        eternal="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" >
      <terracotta /> 
</cache>

<cache name="cache7"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10"
    maxElementsOnDisk="0"
        eternal="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" >
     <terracotta /> 
</cache>

<cache name="cache8"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10"
    maxElementsOnDisk="0"
        eternal="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" >
    <terracotta /> 
</cache>

<cache name="cache9"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10"
    maxElementsOnDisk="0"
        eternal="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" >
    <terracotta /> 
</cache>

<cache name="cache10"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10"
    maxElementsOnDisk="0"
        eternal="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" >
      <terracotta /> 
</cache>

<cache name="DetailStockByKey"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10"
    maxElementsOnDisk="0"
        eternal="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" >
      <terracotta /> 
</cache>
     
<cache name="cache11"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10"
    maxElementsOnDisk="0"
        eternal="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" >
           <terracotta /> 
</cache>

<cache name="cache12"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10"
    maxElementsOnDisk="0"
        eternal="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" >
           <terracotta /> 
</cache>
<cache name="cache13"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10"
    maxElementsOnDisk="0"
        eternal="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" >
           <terracotta /> 
</cache>
<cache name="cache15"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10"
                eternal="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" >
           <!--<terracotta /> -->
</cache>
        
<cache name="cache14"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10"
                eternal="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" >
           <!--<terracotta /> -->
</cache>            
  </ehcache>
```

I also getting a warning like

> WARNING: The configured limit of 1,000 object references was reached
> while attempting to calculate the size of the object graph. Severe
> performance degradation could occur if the sizing operation continues.
> This can be avoided by setting the CacheManger or Cache 
> elements maxDepthExceededBehavior to "abort" or adding stop points
> with @IgnoreSizeOf annotations. If performance degradation is NOT an
> issue at the configured limit, raise the limit value using the
> CacheManager or Cache  elements maxDepth attribute. For
> more information, see the Ehcache configuration documentation.

And I am using -Xmx:1024m for running Terracotta. I didn't face this problem and also my response time is less when running stand-alone ehcache.xml. However when using ehcache with terracotta response time has been increased by 700 times. What should I do so that response time decreases and I won't face this error again?

Comment: The warning is coming from the sizing of your objects in memory that is enabled because of the maxBytesLocalHeap="30%" setting on your cacheManager.
Now whether you're seeing this because of a genuine issue or something else is hard to tell. It is basically telling you that one single entry you put in the cache is over a 1k reference big. Can this actually be correct ?
Also, about the speed, are you saying that 700x on puts, gets, both ?

Comment: So what size i should configure my maxBytesLocalHeap?. The speed is 700x on both . But when i use @IgnoreSizeOf annotation at my 1 object this warning disappears and speed increases a lot.

Comment: Does it sound like even possible that a single cache entry is over 1k different objects ?

Comment: Also not that if both puts and gets are slow, the problem you experience is most probably _not_ related to sizing. Sizing only happens when _adding_ to the cache.